# Migrating CDI ProcessObserverMethod Extension and Custom Scope to Quarkus

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, quarkus

We rely on a cdi extension to read CDI observer methods to automatically bind rabbit mq queue consumers to observer methods alongside providing a custom scope (similar to the request scope, but for incoming amqp messages)

We have been using thorntail for our applications but with 4.0.0 having been cancelled we are looking at migrating to another server or at least using another in new apps. Payara Micro seems like the easiest option but the features of quarkus look promising. However due to the fact it doesnt support CDI extensions we would need to migrate this functionality to a quarkus extension but I am struggling to find much information on how to add these particular features:

```
<T, X> void process(@Observes final ProcessObserverMethod<T, X> observer)
```

and

```
public void registerContext(@Observes final AfterBeanDiscovery event)
    {
        event.addContext(new MessageScopeContext());
    }
```

Comment: Did you look at the AMQP support: https://quarkus.io/guides/amqp ? I think the best is to rewrite your code on this if possible.

Comment: side note: Is your extension open source? I'd be interested in taking a look